Confused with Isolation Forest
Let say, I have the anomaly detection (unsupervised learning) dataset with 10 observations (two features). The datasets is like below:

After executing the model, following are the results (anomalies scores):

The observations which have score as -1 are anomalies.
I have a question about isolation forest or I may not understand how it works correctly.

How isolation forest learns(loss function) while training the data? How it make sure that anomalies detected by model are actually the anomalies?
For example - in above results the observation got scores as -1 could not be the anomalies then how we make sure the results are accurate because in case of unsupervised learning we don't have any target variable means there is no way to calculate errors. So, what would be minimized?

Can anyone please explain to me how it works and provide an example?

cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/129223/55122

The concept of an isolation forest algorithm “learning” is actually a little bit misleading.
The term learning is usually used for either deep learning, where there is a step of backpropagation or some other optimization method being used to adjust weights and biases in a neural network structure based on what the model learns in one step of running, or for supervised machine learning, where the purpose of a loss function is essentially to compare a model’s prediction to the correct answer given in a dataset.
However, isolation forest is different, as it is an algorithm for unsupervised machine learning. The purpose of a loss function is different in unsupervised learning: rather than comparing a model’s prediction to a correct answer, loss functions in unsupervised learning find the difference between a prediction and the input value itself. To think about it in a different way, consider this analogy: a supervised learning model is like a student completing a multiple choice test and then checking an answer key (where the loss function helps them learn from mistakes), whereas an unsupervised learning model is like a student completing the same multiple choice, but they don’t get an answer key, so they have to reason how logical their answer is based on other methods, like whether it picked the letter C too many times (so the loss function doesn’t know the “correct” way to check answers and has to be clever).
If you think about it based on the analogy and how isolation forest works, it actually cleverly identified the anomalies of anything with an F1 of 10 or higher. How isolation forest works in simple terms is that it plots the given input values and randomly restricts the domain and range of the resulting graph. Let’s use your values as the example, setting F1 as the x-axis and F2 as the y-axis of a graph. Once the points are graphed, isolation forest could first randomly say “If I draw a straight line at x=9, which points are to the left of the line and to the right of it?”. After restricting the domain/range, isolation forest creates a binary tree with the results, sending points that were to the left of the restriction line to the left branch of the tree and points that were on or to the right of the line to the right branch. This process is repeated by the algorithm until each point is made alone with the restriction lines (isolated). To ensure randomness doesn’t bias results, isolation forest generates several instances of the algorithm, where each picks different restriction values and creates unique binary trees.
In theory, a point that is already very far from the main cluster of points will be isolated from the others in fewer steps. In other words, if you randomly drew a line through a globe, you are more likely to divide a person in the US and a person in the UK than two people living in the same state of the US. And even if your line got very lucky to divide the two people in the same state, you’re probably not going to get that same luck if you repeat the process several times. Hence, points that are repeatedly found to be farther from others are classified as anomalies, because on average, they end up isolated on their binary tree in fewer steps. In this manner, those super large values are going to be identified as anomalies repeatedly, because “more lines fit between 14 and 24 than 10 and 14” (looking at the points (6, 10), (1, 14), and (17, 24)).
Now, if you don’t agree with the results provided, you’ll have to mess around with isolation forest’s parameters. I won’t go into more depth here, since there is already much length added by the conceptual explanations above. Hope this helps!

Just noticed that your cross post specifically asked about Mahalanobis distance. There’s definitely articles out there on the math, but I’ll say the principle is that since there’s a cluster of points separated by the restriction, Mahalanobis distance is used to find the loss between the center of the cluster to the left of or under (less than) the threshold and the threshold itself. Just a mathematical method being implemented to find the loss by getting a single point from a cluster of points and comparing it to the threshold coordinate value. A simple distance formula calculation.
